# WSO2 API Manager publishing runtime data to DAS, but No Data Available in UI

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I'm using independent wso2 API manager 1.10.0 and wso2 DAS 3.0.0
I have configured REST client for publishing statistics
I published some event and i'm able to see some data in WSO2AM_STATS_DB datasource (api_request_summary,...)

The strange problem is that some statistics are showing in the publisher UI interface (API Subscriptions,API Response Times,API Last Access Times) but in the other pages I'm getting **No Data Available** message
Any explication to this strange message

Answer (score 1):

I think your setup is working fine. You see data in AM_STATS_DB means published data is being analyzed and stored there. There are some pages in the stats page which will show the message "No data available" if there are no relevant data. For example the "Faulty invocation", "Throttled out requests" pages.

If you invoke an api with wrong token, it will appear in the faulty invocation page. If you send requests to an api until they get throttled out (high TPS), it will appear in the throttled out requests page.